# Convert Barcode to a product name

Tags: android, barcode

I made an application for the university, and I have my presentation next week. Everything is ready except for one little detail: I use a barcode scanner, but I only give back the number it scans. I would love to change this number into a product name. After looking for a solution, I didn't find one. Someone who knows how can this be done?

Comment: Ok, according to barcode number create a field in your cloud database. And fetch the details.

Comment: For sure this is a solution that has crossed my mind ceveral times, but I was wondering if it wouldn't be possible to get this online/from an existing databank. To make it more clear, for example if you type in a barcode in google, you get the product.
This implementation would be superior I think.

Comment: Yeah exactly google also fetching info about barcode from various servers around the world.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use google, who uses these databases. If there would be an implementation on this, or a manner that I could come up with an implementation, that would be awsome!

Comment: Are you creating barcode or you are just scanning ?

Comment: I'm scanning it using the ZXing library.

Comment: No i mean the data of barcode is also created by you or you just created an application to scan barcode.

Comment: I just made the application. So it should be able to scan, a varaity of products.

Comment: Ok then you have to check which type of barcode is using by university. Because you have to check that type is supported by zxing or not.

Comment: And if barcode is supported by zxing, then you have to check your code again. Because i am using zxing to scan qr-code and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Mine is working aswell, but if you scan something, what did you get? A number, or a product?

Answer (score 1):

I totally forgot to post it, but I did found a solution. I putted 2 scripts, due to the fact I can't go on android studio from my laptop I can not post my final code over here. If someone really wants to see it, I can do that in the near future. But my solution is as follows: I have some sites where you can give in the number you get from scanning the code and from the get command for getting the info of the site, put this in a file and use the useful stuff by locating it and splitting it.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input barcode");
        if (inputValue != null && inputValue.length() > 0) {
            String url = "https://www.barcodable.com/ean/" + inputValue;
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, doc.title(), "result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a number, and you need a name. That means you need a mapping between a numbers and names somewhere. You don't say where or even if that mapping exists. Assuming it doesn't exist, you can just hardcode it in your app, like:

```
static final SparseArray<String> map;
static {
  map.put(1, "Foo");
  map.put(103, "Bar");
  map.put(529, "Baz");
}
```

Then to use it,

```
String name = map.get(number);
```

Note that `SparseArray` is an Android class that optimizes sparse int / string mappings. You could also use a `Map` or even a `String[]` if you know the bounds of the possible numbers.

Comment: But if number of product changes, then you have to update your APK every time. Instead of this getting product detail from cloud db is a better solution.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of who cares. Will anyone viewing the presentation know, or care where the mapping came from? If no, then do what's easiest. He's not building a product this is a university course.

Comment: Yeah, this could be done, but was hoping for a way to fetch it from the internet. Low effort, high efficiency.

Comment: True, but they will notice it. It's not like show me the application you made, it is more like, show me how and why didn't you do it this way. couldn't it be done better with this. I already have a firebase, so I could couple every product with a name via an interfacedialogue and this database. But was hoping there would be a better solution with a database that already exists or something.

Comment: It helps if you can specify things like this in your question. This is as simple as staging a file somewhere, downloading, and parsing it. Unless your goal is to make this needless complicated when by all means host it in a cloud database.

Comment: @J.Joly There is no centralized database of all barcodes.  Barcodes are split up by manufacturers, whio can assign their ids as they like.  No central registry.  There are companies who try to keep track, but they all charge per lookup or monthly fees.

Comment: I'm going to try to write a little script that sends an http request, gets the http in ascii and extract it from the page. There are some sites that are free and good enough to do. I'll keep you up to date.